# Why gcc doesn't check implicit declaration of function when re-define malloc() in cmd line (-D)?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

Here is my original function (test.c):

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
int main()
    {
        void *p = malloc(1);
        free(p);
        return 0;
    }
```

If I re-define malloc in gcc cmd line with -D, gcc compiles it fine. (why it doesn't complain at my_malloc()?)

```
gcc -c -Wall -D malloc=my_malloc test.c
```

If I change the malloc name in my code to malloc2:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    void *p = malloc2(1);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

And then re-define it, gcc now finally complains:

```
$ gcc -c -Wall -D malloc2=my_malloc test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘my_malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     void *p = malloc2(1);
```

Could someone help me explain why this is happening?

Comment: Did you use `-Wall` in the first case? Please show the command line you use.

Comment: I used -Wall all the time. You can try it. Thanks. 
`gcc -c -Wall -D malloc=my_malloc test.c`

Comment: And I get the expected warning. What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Try C11 or C99 mode. gcc v5.1 uses gnu11 by default, the oldr version gnu90.

Comment: Is `stdlib.h` also included in the first source code? If yes, the question is different and you should edit your question to put it.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add the stdlib.h in the original question. ( I do have it included on my machine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with how the preprocessor is working.

Assuming you `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of your file, the first thing that happens is that this include file is basically imported into your source file.  Next, the define passed in to the command line gets processed.

In the first case, this changes not only the call to `malloc` in your code but also the *declaration* of `malloc` imported from stdlib.h.  So no implicit declaration.  In the second case, the `malloc2` call gets changed, but there's no corresponding declaration that gets swapped out as well.  So  you get the warning.

This is under gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: This totally makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The warning you get in the third case is because you have used a function `malloc2()` (or `my_malloc()` in case you use the `-Dmalloc2=my_malloc` define) without a prototype.  In this case, the `<stdlib.h>` defined prototype doesn't match the define you make in the command line, and you don't get a prototype for it anymore.

As standard behaviour, if you don't include a prototype for a function before it's first use, it defaults to return `int` and to use an undefined number of parameters.  This means that the compiler is assuming you have a `int my_malloc();` function defined elsewhere and as you are trying to assign an integer value to a pointer variable, there's something wrong in your code.

If you want the compiler assume your malloc implementation is *like* the standard library one, just define it with `void *malloc(const size_t);` before that first use.